# Coeficientes de un polinomio en c++

Tags: c++

Buenas necesito saber si existe alguna forma de extraer los coeficientes de un pilinomio para una aplicacion que estoy desarrollando en c++

Ejemplo: `2x^3 + 4x^2 +5x +3`

Coeficientes: `2, 4, 5, 3`

Comment: Bienvenido por favor lee [ask], ¿nos ayudarías editando y mostrando lo que llevas?

Comment: supongo que dividir la cadena, por termino, sacar el primer carácter y donde sea una variable sola ( una letra ) remplazarla por un 1

Comment: La pregunta, en su formato actual, es muy amplia. Cómo recibes el polinomio a procesar? cómo debes mostrar la respuesta?